# how to find buttons with specified text inside using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code structure , and i want to search for span that has text "**Refund Offline**"
and then add the class hide_button to the parent tag " button".

basically I want to hide the button that has "Refund Offline" text.

```
<button class="scalable save submit-button" type="button" id="id_b5295d98b1d6eb3012e2dfd801ede120">

<span>Refund Offline</span>

</button>
```

**Using jQuery**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 24):

```
$("button > span:contains('Refund Offline')").parent().addClass("hide_button");
```

Comment: Is this an exact match for the string 'Refund Offline'?

Comment: No it isn't. It matches all spans which: are child of a button and contain the string 'Refund Offline'

Comment: You could save a function call by using the `$("button:has(> span:contains('Refund Offline'))").addClass('hide_button');` But who knows how many extra calls that makes behind the scenes.

Answer (score 16):

If your text isn't in a span that is a child of button (or you are not 100% sure it is) use

```
$(":contains('Refund Offline')").closest('button').addClass("hide_button");
```

`.closest` will return closest `button` element

Comment: It seems to me that the first selector is going to look at every single node on the page.  Is that correct?  If so.....

Comment: Yes. It look for every node and check for text. You can narrow down it by adding something like `"button :contains"`... Main idea was to say that if you are not sure a text is inside button>span - you can search for more node this way. Of course you should try to write more specific selector. If you can.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$('button span:contains("Refund Offline")').parent().addClass("hide_button");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button span').each ( function() {
    if($(this).text() === "Refund Offline" )
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass ( 'hide_button' );
    }
});
```